# Ошибка при работе с WSDL C#

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

Есть веб-сервис wsdl. Пытаюсь создать клиента, для работы с этим веб-сервисом, но на этапе использования метода выдает ошибку авторизации (видимо).

```
ystem.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Запрос HTTP не разрешен для схемы аутентификации клиента "Anonymous". От сервера получен заголовок аутентификации "Digest realm="http://bankrot.fedresurs.ru/MessageService/WebService.svc", nonce="WeV4+tuehEuzjB/KyZ8SFg==", opaque="ElC4Gn57aEW50veVtLfagA==", stale=false, algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"".
```

У меня есть пример для написания программы:

```
client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = Properties.Settings.Default.Login;
client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

Я попробовал напрямую пароль вписать с логином, но при обращении к методу сервис выдает эксепшн.

```
MessageServiceClient client = new MessageServiceClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = "Login";
        client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = "Pass";
        client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        client.Open();
```

Почему выдается такая ошибка?(

Comment: Настройки привязки (binding) неправильные

Comment: А вот [так](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0aac0110-187e-4a00-a597-f15b768cf16c/passing-client-credentials-to-wcf-service) ?

Comment: Оно.. Получилось.Теперь осталось почитать и понять, что это и как это работает. Спасибо большое.